# Getting information from http response

Tags: node.js, http, web-scraping

This is my first time dealing with web-dev stuff so this may be a stupid question. I am using using axios to send a http request to a certain website, which returns a lot of information. How can I go about extracting the information inside? For example, I am trying to extract the score from the first result in this page (https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=teacherName&queryoption=HEADER&facetSearch=true&query=anne+baranger&schoolName=university+of+california+berkeley&dept=chemistry).

From inspecting the request on Postman, I saw that what I need is in a script element of the html page. How can I parse these information? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Axios

To make a `GET` request in Axios, you would use:

```js
axios.get('https://domain.tld/path').then(response => {
    if (response.success === 200) {
       const { data } = response;

       // Use `data` here
    }
});
```

In your specific case, your get request does not access a JSON API. If you request accessed a JSON API, then `data` will be a regular JavaScript object.

In your specific case, you send a `GET` request to a webpage, which responds with a string of HTML code.

### Your Problem

You are trying to scrape data from a site which does not have the data you want. Of course when you access the site yourself, you see that the data is right there. But as soon as the page loads, you will see "Loading...". This is because the site makes a JavaScript call to their internal API to access the search results.

When you make an HTTP request you only get the data that is sent back. No scripts are imported to your own site, no JavaScript is executed, and stylesheets do not render. You are simply stuck with the HTML string. Any data not enclosed in the HTML string will be out of your reach.

### A Potential Solution

What you are working towards is actually called web scraping. Web scraping is when you access a webpage, simulate all the scripts that occur during load time, wait for the external page to finish loading, then begin collecting visible data from the page.

To scrape the web, you will need to write a web scraper which runs on a server. Then you will require a **headless browser**. A popular headless browser is Puppeteer. An alternative is Selenium.

A headless browser is simply Google Chrome, Safari, or FireFox, but without the window. Usually you run your browser in a window, but on your server, since everything is automated, no window needs to be opened, but the JS/DOM just need to be simulated. This will allow scripts to run, stylesheets to be rendered, and all content will be loaded (since this is an actual browser running the site).

### Web Scraping Solution

If you have never written a web scraper before, you can use this [GitHub repository (JustData)](https://github.com/VirajShah21/JustData) to learn about it.

You can checkout a live example of the data [JustData scrapes here](http://just-data.herokuapp.com).

In the GitHub repository, navigate to [server/src/Scraper](https://github.com/VirajShah21/JustData/tree/main/server/src/Scraper).

[image: Just Data]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried puppeteer before but it was stuck at (from screenshot) asking for cookies page. Do you know of any ways to circumvent that?

Comment: @Tsz, there is no screenshot here. But if you get prompted with a cookies page, you can simulate a button click by using `document.querySelector('.agree-cookies-btn').click()`